# Why React.js is so difficult to learn?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

What's wrong with me?

I have learnt React.js for 6 months. It have a lot of chapters that we need to learn and I also lost my way. Can u drop your experiences with React.js step by step. I really need your advice, please!

Comment: Practice basics regularly and then build simple apps like TODO, cuz you can check other implementations and refer to new [beta docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/describing-the-ui)

Comment: You need to have patience. React.js is not that difficult once you get a grasp of the fundamentals and when you start to understand how it works. I suggest you to read about React components lifecycle, how state updates work, the most important hooks, etc. Also, as others already suggested, start building simple projects and try to spend at least 30mins per day getting used to React. Don't forget to enjoy the process!

Comment: What is TODO and which hook do we use mostly?

Comment: "TODO" is a "to do app" or reminder app. It's a common "play" project used to learn a new technology.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) found on their website. It features making a basic tic-tac-toe game using React while explaining the core concepts. In my opinion it is a much better way for understanding what React does best and how you can use it effectively.

Comment: Thank u so much for sharing. I'll try my best to follow your advice